# How to split a list of number into ranges with a fixed interval with SQL?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Let's say I have a table like this

[image]

I want to calculate the frequency ( How many times that product exists in that price range ), in intervals of "50"

So eventually it will give me a table like

[image]

Interval for range will be lets pretend a fixed 50
We don't know highest and lowest price of these each products.

So I will run the query and it will give a table as shown above.

I got a query like this but it didn't work. It gives this error ( I cannot edit server config )

This is the query

```
select product, count(*) as frequency,
       floor(price / 50) as range_start, floor(price / 50) + 50 as range_end
from t 
group by product, floor(price / 50)
order by product, min(price)
```

This is the error

```
 [42000][1055] Expression #4 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'price' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

After that I tried this ( changed floor(price / 50) to floor(min(price) / 50)

```
select product, count(*) as frequency,
       floor(min(price) / 50) as range_start, floor(min(price) / 50) + 50 as range_end
from t 
group by product, floor(price / 50)
order by product, min(price)
```

This query worked but it gives ranges like

[image]

Comment: did you try to add "floor(price / 50) + 50" to the GROUP BY part of the first query?

Comment: @Nikita it worked. But range is 2,52 - 3,53 rather than 0,50 -50,100

Comment: Please note that images are frowned upon here for the reasons outlined in [this link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530). In future, could you please post your table structures as DDL and your data as DML - perhaps as a fiddle (but be sure to post that information here also). Help us to help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select product, count(*) as frequency,
       50 * floor(price / 50) as range_start,
       50 * (floor(price / 50) + 1) as range_end
group by product, 50 * floor(price / 50), 50 * (floor(price / 50) + 1)
order by product, min(price)
```

Comment: [HY000][1111] Invalid use of group function

The problem is with "min" in group by I think since I got this error in the IDE

"Aggregate calls are not allowed here "

Comment: @SNaRe, sorry, I copy+pasted the wrong part :) Fixed.